# Eclipse imported but default activity not found

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, android-activity

I just imported my eclipse project to android studio, and It studio converted everything fine. But while running the error message shows: Default Activity Not Found.

> my manifest file: https://hastebin.com/yigakupoho.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your default activity as android.intent.action.MAIN, like that:

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```